# How do I compile in debug mode? (netbeans, java, maven)

Tags: java, debugging, netbeans, compiler-construction, maven

I am facing annotation/persistence errors in a project and the persistence library throws a

> `NullPointerException when trying to resolve the entities (org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.classes.EntityAccessor.discoverMappedSuperclassesAndInheritanceParents(EntityAccessor.java:224)).`

How do I debug errors like these to find more about the cause of the error?

Setting a breakpoint in `EntityAccessor` and compiling for debug doesn't work, the compiler itself seems to be not running in debug mode.

I am using Netbeans / Java / Maven.

Comment: the compiler throws this exception or the app at startup? and post a full stacktrace, please.

Answer (score 44):

From what I understand, you want debug in the compilation- not maven in debug mode.

Using mvn to compile, use debug mode through following way:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>8</source>
        <target>8</target>
        <debug>true</debug>
        <debuglevel>lines,vars,source</debuglevel> 
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

debuglevel can be any of the three values entered in CSV format 
To highlight, **debug** and **debuglevel** are important nodes included in the maven.

Hope it helps in some way.

Reference: [maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html)

Comment: "From what I understand, you want debug in the compilation- not maven in debug mode." 
Exactly. I landed here looking for the later, OP wanted a solution for the former. Prunge's answer covers that.

Answer (score 6):

You can debug any Maven goal in NetBeans going to `/Project Properties/Actions/`, select the goal you wan to debug, in the last option **Set Properties** choose **Add**, and then select **Debug Maven build**.

Answer (score 4):

Are you running Maven in debug mode?

To run Maven in debug mode, use the command *mvnDebug* instead of *mvn* to build your project and then attach to it using your IDE.  Debug breakpoints should be hit.

I've done this with Eclipse, mostly when trying to debug my own annotation processors, but it's also handy for debugging Maven plugins.

I'd imagine debugging a JPA processor would not be trivial - you might be better off looking at the whole error message again or posting it in your question.

Comment: How should I run it, so I can attach to it from Netbeans?  Question here:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/33246407/1735836

Answer (score 4):

**You need to have the `jpda.listen=maven` property set.**

In Netbeans 8+:

**1.** Select the module you want to debug when building.

**2.** Right-click to open the context menu, and select `Properties`.

**3.** Select the `Actions` category.

**4.** Then select the `Clean and build project` Action.

**5.** Under the `Set Properties` section, select `Add` > `Debug Maven Build`.

**6.** Click the `OK` button to close and save your settings.

Now you should be able to set breakpoints and debug maven plugins and dependencies.

Comment: But I am still getting the message that I need to set "-g option", maybe you know how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to set your breakpoints in the `org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.classes.EntityAccessor` class, and that should stop during the start up of your server (which you would need to start in debug mode). This is not really compilation, but just JPA loading its metadata from class annotations. Because your JPA provider's code is not something you can understand easily or modify, I would suggest that instead of debugging you try searching for your specific error on the net and see if somebody else has experienced it (i.e. might be a bug on Eclipse Link), it's common for these libraries to throw uninformative exceptions like a Null Pointer when your entities are not annotated correctly.