# Eclipse ONLY hits break point when exception is thrown, but not on any other line of code I set break point on

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have a problem with Eclipse and one of my apps. Eclipse ONLY hits breakpoints when I throw an exception but not when it runs other lines of code "normally".

I am running the project in

```
C:\.....SmashDataServiceExternal\processor\bin
```

While my source code is under a different directory:

```
C:\.......\SmashDataProcessorExternal\...
```

When I try to run my app, it does not hit any of lines of code normally, but if I break on an Exception and I make my App throw an exception, then Eclipse breaks on the correct line in the correct source file.

i.e:

```
    System.out.println("HISTORIC DATA: " + historicData.getDatasetId());
    System.out.println("HISTORIC DATA TYPE: " + historicData.getReplayEventTypeId());
    outputInputRequest(outputEvent);
    logger.info("Sent BatchJobRequest for batchId {}, sessionId {} for byTime request", outputEvent.getBatchId(batchIdFlyweight), outputEvent.getSessionId(sessionIdFlyweight) );
    if (1==1) {
        throw new NullPointerException();
        }
```

I set break point on every single line above, my app actually prints out the statements but does not break until nullpointer gets thrown.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/14dNg.jpg

I would appreciate any advise on how to get Eclipse to break properly.

Thank you.

Comment: Is Eclipse itself compiling your sources?

Comment: No, it is being complied through maven

Comment: Maven might not be configured to keep debugging symbols, then. Breakpoints where the line was already executed, which requires that information be in the class file, would have a checkmark on them.

Comment: @nitind 

Hey, I tried setting a debug flag [<debug>true</debug>]







But I'm still not getting the breakpoints to hit.

Is there anyway to see the "checkmarks" inside the class files?

Thank you!

Comment: You're not trying to debug the install, you want debug enabled on compilations. https://stackoverflow.com/a/16480700/27905